# What is a Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: apex, null-pointer

What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I avoid them?

Comment: Hi ren, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. Are you running into this problem in your code? If so, please share what you have so far and point out where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome ren, in addition to what @AdrianLarson said this is an incredibly common problem developers face. Have you tried browsing SFSE to find your answer?

Answer (score 5):

There are an infinite number of variations for the cause of this error. Sometimes it can be very subtle. But the root cause is when you assume a variable is not null, and then try to call instance methods on it. That will cause the system to try to de-reference the null variable. For example:

```
Date notInstantiated;
system.debug(notInstantiated.format());
```

If you ran the above in `Execute Anonymous`, you would get an error like:

> Line: 2, Column: 1
>   System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

If you are having a hard time figuring out the cause of your error, this information is critical in the debugging process. Critically, here you can see that Line 2 is the problem, and from there deduce that an attempt to de-reference `notInstantiated` is the probable cause.

It would be a waste of time to try to demonstrate all the ways you can get a `NullPointerException`, as it is one of the most common errors in `Apex` code. But that is the basic principle. If you make a bad assumption that a variable is not null and you're wrong, you see this error.

Comment: Can you mention line numbers too?

Comment: @Keith I don't follow what you're getting at. You just mean the second line would throw? Sure I can add it.

Comment: Sorry for being cryptic. Meant that as well as the type of exception and the message, the line number information reported is just as important in tracking down problems.